# print text file from web server to python program print errors

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to print a text a text file from a webserver in a python program but I am receiving errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated, here is my code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import urllib2

GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(5,GPIO.OUT)

true = 1

while(true):

                try:

 response = urllib2.urlopen('http://148.251.158.132/k.txt')
                        status = response.read()

            except urllib2.HTTPError, e:

                                    print e.code

            except urllib2.URLError, e:
                                    print e.args

           print status
            if status=='bulbion':
                           GPIO.output(5,True)


            elif status=='bulbioff':



                            GPIO.output(5,False)
```

Comment: What are the "print" errors your receiving?

Comment: >>> %Run rasbpi.py
  File "C:\Users\Pandey\Desktop\pro\programm\rasbpi.py", line 12
    print status
               ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

Comment: srry formissunderstand

Comment: File "C:\Users\Pandey\Desktop\pro\programm\rasbpi.py", line 16
    print status
    ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

Comment: You can fix the error on line 16 by using `print (status)` instead of `print status`

Comment: >>> %Run rasbpi.py
  File "C:\Users\Pandey\Desktop\pro\programm\rasbpi.py", line 16
    print (status)
                 ^
SyntaxError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: ``print(status)`` no space between print and status

Comment: That Python file should really be indented properly to work.

Answer (score 0):

By your comments, it appears your error: **"SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to print"**, is caused by excluding parentheses/brackets in your print statements. People usually experience these errors after they update their python version, as the old print statements never required parentheses. The other error: **"SyntaxError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level"**, is because your print statement on line 16 is one space behind all of your other statements on that indentation level, you can fix this problem by moving the print statement one space forward.
Changing your code to this should fix the problems:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import urllib2

GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(5,GPIO.OUT)

true = 1

while(true):

    try:

        response = urllib2.urlopen('http://148.251.158.132/k.txt')
            status = response.read()

                except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
                                    print (e.code)

                except urllib2.URLError, e:
                                    print (e.args)

            print (status)
                if status=='bulbion':
                           GPIO.output(5,True)

            elif status=='bulbioff':
                           GPIO.output(5,False)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: >>> %Run new.py
  File "C:\Users\Pandey\Desktop\pro\programm\new.py", line 16
    response = urllib2.urlopen("http://148.251.158.132/k.txt")
                                                             ^
SyntaxError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: its showing error if i would have option to share screen shot i would share screen >>> %Run new.py
  File "C:\Users\Pandey\Desktop\pro\programm\new.py", line 16
    response = urllib2.urlopen('http://148.251.158.132/k.txt')
                                                             ^
SyntaxError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: nope the is not working brother the same error >>> %Run new.py
  File "C:\Users\Pandey\Desktop\pro\programm\new.py", line 16
    response = urllib2.urlopen('http://148.251.158.132/k.txt')
                                                             ^
SyntaxError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level  plz run code on your pc then share brother

Comment: @varunpandey try now?

Comment: @varunpandey can't run the code on my pc because I don't have an RPI, sorry

Comment: @varunpandey look, my python command prompt is broken, I'm trying to fix your program off memory, can you please just try the code I provide for you so we can find a solution to your problem, besides, it's nearly fixed anyway:)